# How can I configure GridDB's replication settings for high availability?

Tags: configuration, replication, production-environment, high-availability, griddb

I'm using GridDB in a production environment and want to ensure high availability in case of node failures. I've read the GridDB documentation; replication is the way to go. However, how can I configure the replication settings to achieve the level of availability I need?

Here's what I currently have in my **gridstore.json** file:

```
{
  "dataStore": [
    {
      "name": "my_container",
      "type": "COLLECTION",
      "columnInfo": [
        {
          "columnName": "id",
          "type": "STRING",
          "options": "PRIMARY_KEY"
        },
        {
          "columnName": "value",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ],
      "rowKey": {
        "keyType": "STRING"
      }
    }
  ],
  "partitionInfo": {
    "partitionType": "HASH",
    "partitionCount": 4
  },
  "replicationInfo": {
    "replicationType": "ASYNC",
    "replicationFactor": 2,
    "heartbeatInterval": 1000,
    "heartbeatTimeout": 5000
  }
}
```